# Behavior of VALUES clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, ansi-sql

In Postgres, according to its [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-values.html), the following works:

```
select 1 as column1, 'one' as column2
union all
select 2, 'two'
union all
select 3, 'three'
```

however its extension:

```
select * from (select 1 as column1, 'one' as column2
union all
select 2, 'two'
union all
select 3, 'three')
```

results in error:

[image]

Similarly, while this works (assuming Postgres creates internal alias?):

```
values(1,'a'), (2, 'b')
```

the following results in error, requiring an alias:

```
select * from (values(1,'a'), (2, 'b'))
```

and only starts working when such alias is provided:

```
select * from (values(1,'a'), (2, 'b')) t(z,y)
```

Same inconsistency seems to also apply to SELECT clause, i.e.:

```
select 1, 2
```

works independently but not as a subselect:

```
select * from (select 1, 2)
```

unless provided with an alias:

```
select * from (select 1, 2) t(a, b)
```

Would it not be a logical extension of the behavior of clauses dealing with sets (**SELECT, VALUES**, etc.) to assume some internal alias when used inside another select like Postgres already does when use those clauses independently?

What was the reasoning that lead to such inconsistency in design?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for using `VALUES` with select is certainly different than how it used in most flavors of SQL with insert.  That being said, the issue here with Postgres actually seems to be that the `VALUES` clause needs to be wrapped in parentheses as a subquery in order for it to be eligible for use with select (it won't work otherwise).  Therefore, we can think of the following as being equivalent to any other subquery:

```
select *
from
(
    values (1,'a'), (2, 'b')
) t;
```

If the `VALUES` clause were replaced with a select, we would have to alias the subquery, and the same holds true with `VALUES`.  As to *why* Postgres chose to do this, you might have to check the documentation or ask a question on their forum.